# Как настроить cmd на c++ 17 версии? У меня MinGW последней версии, но пишет что С++ не 17 версии. Но через CodeBlock все работает

Tags: c++, cmd, mingw

Ребят, помогите. Учу си++. И уже который раз в книге используются функции 17-ой версии. На CodeBlock(типа Visual Studio) у меня все работает, там сделал по туториалллу, но вот в командной строке файл не компилируется. Я использую в основном gVim, а не CodeBlock. Привык очень. создаю там файлы, и вызываю их через командную строку. Но пишет ошибку до сих пор:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:8: error: 'string_view' is not a member of 'std'
    5 |   std::string_view text{ "hello" }; // view the text "hello", which is stored in the binary
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:5:8: note: 'std::string_view' is only available from C++17 onwards
main.cpp:6:8: error: 'string_view' is not a member of 'std'
    6 |   std::string_view str{ text }; // view of the same "hello"
```

Windows 10. MinGW 9.0.2 вроде.

Comment: Какой командой компилируете в командной строке? Попробуйте с флажком `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @Croessmah простите за мою глупость) но в командной строке данная команда не распознается.. "-std" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat простите за мою глупость) но в командной строке данная команда не распознается.. "-std" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Comment: Это нужно добавлять к той команде, которой вы компилируете.

Comment: @Croessmah блин) работает, но нет ли способа сделать это как стандарт запуска? иначе каждый раз придется вводить дополнительные символы)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо большое! работает! но нет ли способа сделать это как стандарт запуска? иначе каждый раз придется вводить дополнительные символы)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make

Comment: Как создадите makefile, прямо в gVim сохраняйте исходник и пишите make.